# BC3 - Folder Compare shows files as 'Binary different', though differences are unimportant?

Tags: diff, beyondcompare

I am trying to compare a folder with a zip file to see if there are any meaningful differences between the source files they contain.

I have set my compare to ignore the folder structure for simplicity, and checked the Ignore Unimportant Differences option.

When I perform the compare, it shows many files have binary differences (≠).  However, if I open these files in a new view to see the differences, it shows that all differences are unimportant.  When I go back to the folder view, I see the status has changed to the ≈ sign.

Is there any way to force Beyond Compare to automatically perform this comparison, so I don't have to do this manually?  In the rules menu, I have checked "Compare contents" and "Rules-based comparison", but it does not seem to be working.

[image: Rules Settings]

Is this a bug?  Is this a limitation when comparing against zip files?  Are my settings correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to `Handling` tab and change `Archive handling` check-box to `As folder always`:

[image: Beyond Compare - Session Settings - Folder Compare]

From [documentation](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?sessiondirhandling.html):

> ## Archive handling (e.g. zip files)
>
> **As folders always** treats archive files like regular folders.

Comment: I changed this setting as shown, and re-did the compare I did the other day.  It still shows the files as 'binary different' until I manually open them (at which point it changes to 'unimportant differences').

Comment: Have you changed the setting for all sessions (`Also update session defaults` in checkbox at the bottom of dialog)?

Comment: Yes, I checked the box to change the setting for session defaults.

Comment: What version of Beyond Compare do you have? I have 4.0.7 and it works for me well.

Comment: I have version 3.2.4.  Unfortunately, I highly doubt I'll be able to upgrade.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend to upgrade (it is for free if you bought a license after 1.1.2013). Guys behind Beyond Compare are really working on it, adding new features, fixing bugs.

Comment: Accepting the answer and an upvote.  After my company upgraded everyone to BC4, I have verified that this works correctly.  Must be a bug in the older version.  Thanks!